# How do I stop the auto close of semi colons in CSS in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: html, sublime-text-3, css

When I make a property in CSS and use the open bracket semicolon it auto creates the close bracket semicolon. How can I disable this in Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little guide to disable autocomplete.

1. You go to Settings > Preferences
2. There must be a property named `"auto_complete"`
3. Turn it from `true` to `false`
4. Edit: Put also "auto_match_enabled" to false

Hope that helped

Comment: Hey it didn't help. I did "auto_close_tags": false, for tags in html but "auto_complete": false, didn't stop the semi colon from closing itself

Comment: Why even a semicolut autocompletes itself?

Comment: When you use sublime and you press { in css it creates a closed bracket to the side of it. I want to create the closed bracket myself

Comment: Maybe you mean the "auto_match_enabled": false option. Try that

Answer (score 0):

You can it disable it with the auto_complete setting. To disable it, add this line to the right-hand pane of Preferences >> Settings:

"auto_complete": false

reference from : https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/auto_complete.html